# How do I search and edit a specific item on Mongodb?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a banking application with MERN stack and have a form on the Create Account Page that saves name, email, password, and balance to a table of users on Monogodb. I want to be able to then go to another form on the Withdraw/Deposit Page and enter an amount and email and it search through the table and update that users balance.

I tried to connect directly to mongoose and then use findOneandUpdate and $set to find the email and change the balance but, it is not changing the balance.

Deposit Page

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import React from "react";
import Card from "../../partials/Card";
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('http://localhost:4000/users');


function DepositPage() {
   
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const [show, setShow]     = useState(true);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState('');  
  
    return (
      <Card
        bgcolor="dark"
        header="Deposit"
        status={status}
        body={show ? 
          <DepositForm setShow={setShow} setStatus={setStatus}/> :
          <DepositMsg setShow={setShow}/>}
      />
    )
  }
  
  function DepositMsg(props){
    return (<>
      <h5>User Successfully Deposited into Their Account</h5>
      <button type="submit" 
        className="btn btn-light" 
        onClick={() => props.setShow(true)}>
          Make Another Deposit
      </button>
    </>);
  } 
  
  function DepositForm(props){
    const [email, setEmail]   = useState('');
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');
    
    
    function handle(){
      
    users.findOneAndUpdate({email: email}, {$set:{balance: amount}}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error updating data");
      }

      console.log(doc)
    })

      props.setStatus('');      
      props.setShow(false);
    }
  
    return(<>
  
      Email<br/>
      <input type="input" 
        className="form-control" 
        placeholder="Enter email" 
        value={email} 
        onChange={e => setEmail(e.currentTarget.value)}/><br/>
        
      Amount<br/>
      <input type="number" 
        className="form-control" 
        placeholder="Enter amount" 
        value={amount} 
        onChange={e => setAmount(e.currentTarget.value)}/><br/>
  
      <button type="submit" 
        className="btn btn-light" 
        onClick={handle}>
          Deposit
      </button>
  
    </>);
  }

 export default DepositPage
```

Router Page

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const schemas = require('../models/schemas')

router.post('/users/:a', async(req, res) => {
  const {name, email, password, balance} = req.body
  const action = req.params.a
  
  switch(action) {
    case "send":
      const userData = {name: name, email: email, password: password, balance: balance}
      const newUser = new schemas.Users(userData)
      const saveUser = await newUser.save()
      if (saveUser) {
        res.send('User created')
      } else {
        res.send('Failed to create user. Please make sure all fields are filled and try again.')
      }
      break;

      default:
        res.send('Invalid Request')
        break
  }

  res.end()
})

module.exports = router
```

index.js (server)

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const router = require('./routes/router')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv/config')

const app =  express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
    optionSuccessStatus: 200
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use('/', router)

const dbOptions = {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true}
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI, dbOptions)
.then(() => console.log('DB Connected!'))
.catch(err => console.log(err))

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

schemas page

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type:String, required:true},
    email: {type:String, required:true},
    password: {type:String, required:true},
    balance: {type:Number, required:true},
    entryDate: {type:Date, default:Date.now}
})



const Users = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema, 'users')
const mySchemas = {'Users':Users}

module.exports = mySchemas
```

CreateAccount Page

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import React from 'react';
import Card from '../../partials/Card';

function CreateAccountPage() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const [show, setShow]     = useState(true);
    const [status, setStatus] = useState('');


    let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } };
  
    return (
      <Card
        bgcolor="dark"
        header="Create Account"
        status={status}
        body={show ? 
          <CreateForm setShow={setShow}/> : 
          <CreateMsg setShow={setShow}/>}
      />
    )
  }
  
  function CreateMsg(props){
    return(<>
      <h5>Success</h5>
      <button type="submit" 
        className="btn btn-light" 
        onClick={() => props.setShow(true)}>Add another account</button>
    </>);
  }
  
  function CreateForm(props){
    const [name, setName]         = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail]       = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [balance, setBalance]   = useState(0);
    const [error, setError] = useState('')

    const axiosPostData = async() => {
        const postData = {
          name: name,
          email: email,
          password: password,
          balance: balance
        }

        await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/send', postData)
        .then(res => setError(<p className="success">{res.data}</p>))
    }

    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        axiosPostData()
        props.setShow(false);
        }


    return ( <>      

    <form name="createAcctForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
      Name<br/>
      <input type="text"
        id="name" 
        className="form-control" 
        placeholder="Enter name" 
        value={name} 
        onChange={e => setName(e.currentTarget.value)} 
        required
        /><br/>
  
      Email address<br/>
      <input type="text" 
        id="email"
        className="form-control" 
        placeholder="Enter email" 
        value={email} 
        onChange={e => setEmail(e.currentTarget.value)}
        required
        /><br/>
  
      Password<br/>
      <input type="password" 
        id="password"
        className="form-control" 
        placeholder="Enter password" 
        value={password} 
        onChange={e => setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)}
        minLength="8"
        /><br/>
  
        <button type="submit" 
        className="btn btn-light" 
        >Create Account</button>
    </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default CreateAccountPage
```

Also I am very sorry if my formatting is rough. I am still very new to using stackoverflow.

Comment: What is the outcome of the `console.log` when you perform the operation? What is the target document and what are the parameters provided to the command?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

MongoDB and Mongoose are backend techs for interacting with DBs from a server-side environment. On the frontend (React) side, you cannot directly connect to the MongoDB database or use Mongoose. Instead, you need to make HTTP requests from your React components to your backend API, which will handle the database operations using Mongoose. The Node.js `require` keyword can be used on your server or terminal runtime. But `import` will work as well in ecma script 6+ supporting environments too. For the back-end side:

```
// choose between import or require depending on your javascript runtime
// const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database-name', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Mongo error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected!');
});
```

That above snippet should import mongoose from your library or NPM modules into the backend server API (express). Using mongoose requires a backend javascript environment to compile and run. Since Node.js and other backends utilize C++, C, Rust, etc. at the system level, mongoose package will need to be configured to interact with the Mongo API. In the `mongoose.connect` method we establish a network with the default port number of Mongo DB, 27017. The `database-name` can be any. If you are using mongo community version, paid, or other versions, after you start your database engine, this should complete the connection and configuration for your react app to interact with the database. I like to use the MongoDB Compass program for a GUI interface with my mongo DBs https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass
But you could also run mongo scripts in a terminal env

Your next steps would be to define a Mongo schema or schemas depending on how many data structures you need. In Node.js, see the `require` syntax:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  password: String,
  balance: Number,
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Save that into a folder named 'models' or another like 'structures'. Then for each schema make a new file describing it, like 'User.js'
It depends if you want to call it update, depositAmount, or something like that.

```
import User from '../models/User';

// define update, deposit, etc. function logic

async function handle() {
  try {
    const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { email: email },
      { $inc: { balance: parseInt(amount) } },
      { new: true }
    );

    console.log(updatedUser);
    props.setStatus('');
    props.setShow(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error updating data", error);
  }
}
```

Use the built-in method from mongoose `findOneAndUpdate` and we can update the user data. Mongo comes with a unique uid that can assist in identifying users.

You also asked about needing to set up your front end API requests inside of the form. Using `fetch` API or `axios`, put functions that define updating user data in a folder called 'helpers'. We will make HTTP requests to the server to actually handle the database interactions with the react code. In a new component, let's say 'DepositPage.js' we can make an HTTP request to our server and initiate an update on the User collection.
Based on your code from the component you, the react component should look something like:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function DepositPage() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

  const handleDeposit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/deposit", {
        email: email,
        amount: amount,
      });

      console.log(response.data);
      setStatus("User successfully deposited into their account");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error depositing:", error);
      setStatus("Error depositing. Please try again.");
    }

    setShow(false);
  };

  const handleAnotherDeposit = () => {
    setShow(true);
    setStatus("");
    setEmail("");
    setAmount("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Deposit</h2>

      {show ? (
        <form onSubmit={handleDeposit}>
          <label>
            Email:
            <input
              type="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            Amount:
            <input
              type="number"
              value={amount}
              onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Deposit</button>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h4>{status}</h4>
          <button onClick={handleAnotherDeposit}>Make Another Deposit</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default DepositPage;
```

I'm assuming you are using `express`, but the HTTP is the same.
`axios.post()` is how react.js can send data to your server/API. With the param `/api/deposit`, the express routes should be set up for these endpoints.

If you need more info on setting up express let me know. Choosing between import and require is mostly determined by your style of choice, or your specific environment requirements.

EDIT:

// React component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function CreateUser() {
  const FULL_API_URL = 'local host path and port to server'
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${FULL_API_URL}/users/send`, {
        name,
        email,
        password,
        balance
      });

      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating user:", error);
      // error logic stuff ...
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Create User</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Email:
          <input
            type="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Password:
          <input
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Balance:
          <input
            type="number"
            value={balance}
            onChange={(e) => setBalance(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Create User</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateUser;
```

Comment: I added my schemas and index.js pages from my server in my question. I am slightly confused if I add the helpers folder to frontend or backend. Also would I add the node require keyword snippet to index or router? Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Your welcome, the helpers folder would be in the backend and contain as many handler functions you need like for changing data. The choice or import or require is somewhat arbitrary as most browsers now have built-in support for import. I still use require often in Node.js

Comment: So would I have to redo how I connect to mongoose or is how I have it setup in the index with the .env file okay? I can get the accounts to save to mongo I just cannot update the balance when on the deposit/withdraw pages

Comment: In your index setup you could change '/users/:a' to be '/users/send', or just ensure that your axios pathname is exactly the one on express route. Env files should be fine in node. Since backend looks good then you just need the react component setup. Since it is a bit of code, I will edit my original post at the bottom with

Comment: I did not realize you were making an create user component. I added the one I have already been using in my edit above. It works and posts to the user table like I want. Just struggling to then get it by email and edit the balance

Comment: Can you elaborate on the logic/feature you want to achieve when you mentioned this?
'struggling to then get it by email and edit the balance'